# How to rename a file according his folder name via batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, batch-rename

*I have this part of batch script which is doing following:*
-There is a main folder, in the main folder are two files (movie & subtitle file) and one Sub-folder called 'Subtitles'
-This script takes the name of the movie file and renames with it the subtitle file + moves the subtitle file into the 'Subtitles' sub-folder and then renames the main folder. So at the end we have one movie name, which is used on the subtitle file and on the main folder as well.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


cd /D "%~DP0"
echo BASE FOLDER: %cd%
set n=0
for /D %%a in (*) do (
set /A n+=1
cd "%%a"
echo ==================================================================
echo Processing folder: %%a


for %%b in (*.avi *.mp4 *.mkv) do set movieName=%%~Nb
echo Movie name: !movieName!
for %%b in (*.srt *.sub) do (
   move "%%b" "Subtitles\!movieName!%%~Xb"
  echo File "%%b" moved and renamed to "Subtitles\!movieName!%%~Xb"
)


cd ..
ren "%%a" "!movieName!"
echo Folder "%%a" renamed to "!movieName!" 

)
echo ==================================================================
echo %n% FOLDERS PROCESSED
pause
```

**!!!!! What I need is following: !!!!!**
-**I need to make it vice versa**, so the **name would be taken from the main folder** and not from the movie file, so the **name of the main folder would be used on the movie and on the subtitle file**.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


cd /D "%~DP0"
echo BASE FOLDER: %cd%
set n=0
for /D %%a in (*) do (
set /A n+=1
cd "%%a"
echo ==================================================================
echo Processing folder: %%a
set movieName=%%~a


for %%b in (*.avi *.mp4 *.mkv) do (
   ren "%%~b" "!movieName!%%~Xb"
   echo Movie file "%%b" renamed to "!movieName!%%~Xb"
)

for %%b in (*.srt *.sub) do (
   move "%%~b" "Subtitles\!movieName!%%~Xb"
   echo File "%%b" moved and renamed to "Subtitles\!movieName!%%~Xb"
)


cd ..

)
echo ==================================================================
echo %n% FOLDERS PROCESSED
pause
```

Comment: :)) It was you again. Thank you...again! It works as it should work!

Answer (score 0):

I have written this python script, to move and rename the .srt file to the root folder. If it can help someone.

```
import os, shutil
directory= r'\\c:\path_to_main_folder'
working_directory = directory + "\Subs"
for file in os.listdir(working_directory):   
    for subtitle_file in os.listdir(os.path.join(working_directory,file)) :
        if subtitle_file.endswith(".srt"):
            name = os.path.join(directory, file + ".srt")
            if not os.path.exists(name): # sometimes there are multiple srt file in the subs, hence it checks if it already exist if yes it skip
                print(f"Moving {file} to folder {directory}")
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(os.path.join(working_directory, file),subtitle_file), os.path.join(directory, subtitle_file))
                print(f"Renaming {subtitle_file} to {file}")
                os.rename(os.path.join(directory, subtitle_file), os.path.join(directory, file + ".srt"))    
# shutil.rmtree(working_directory)      # to delete the folder subs afterwards
print("Done")
```