# Script to rename files to parent folder, move renamed file and delete empty folder

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

Wondering if anyone here can help me out. I'm using Windows 7 and have a collection of movies and TV shows in individual folders which I'd like to be renamed to that of the folder name. For example:

```
../Media Files/Example Movie (2013)/EM2013.avi
```

to:

```
../Media Files/Example Movie (2013)/Example Movie (2013).avi
```

I'd then like the newly named file to be moved to the `Media Files` folder, and for the (then empty) folder to be deleted. So:

```
..Media Files/Example Movie (2013).avi
```

I've searched for a solution but only found scripts which do one or the other ([How to rename a file according his folder name via batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055495/how-to-rename-a-file-according-his-folder-name-via-batch-script)) - I'm after a script that can do all three things in one go as I will be adding movies and TV shows to the `Media Files` folder on a regular basis. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help and apologize if anything similar has been asked before.

Comment: You say you found partial solutions, why don't you try to combine them in a single code? if you have questions, come back, post your code, and we will be happy to help you!

Comment: Hi - sorry would have attempted that but I'm completely new to this - my programming skills stretch as far as HTML :| In fact I was originally searching google for a program to execute my requirements when I found out it could be done in a script!

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET target=.\media files
FOR /f "delims=" %%t IN (
 ' dir /b /ad "%target%" ' ) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN (
  ' dir /b /a-d "%target%\%%t\*.*" ' ) DO (
  ECHO MOVE "%target%\%%t\%%f" "%target%\%%t%%~xf"
  ECHO RD "%target%\%%t"
  )
)
PAUSE
```

Should display the required operations. Remove the ECHO keyword after verification to execute

Comment: Thanks for this mate - and apologise for being a complete n00b - but I have no experience of using scripts - tried copying and pasting this into a notepad file and saving as code.bat but when I ran it a black window popped up for a milisecond which had 'File not found' in it.I'm not too sure what you meant by removing the ECHO keyword after verification to execute...tried googling to understand the Echo function but couldn't understand it properly...again sorry for being a dumb n00b with this!

Comment: n00bitude is no problem - we've all got to start somewhere. I'd suggest that you start by `Start>(All) Programs>Accessories>Command Prompt` Right-click and select `Send to>Desktop` which will create a shortcut to Command Prompt (commonly renamed `DOS`) on your desktop. You could then play with the shortcut properties (right-click and select Properties) to establish whatever colour background and text you desire - and number of lines and width of window and font and fontsize. Personally, I use 18-point Lucida and yellow text on a black background. Your preferences may be different.

Comment: The point is that having done that, you can run a `"DOS SESSION"` - a DOS emulator, just like we had thirty years ago. When a batch file finishes, you get a prompt again until you execute the command `EXIT`. To run `notepad` all you need do is to type `notepad batchfilename.bat` and notepad will open batchfilename.bat for editing. When you're done, typing `batchfilename` at the prompt will run the batchfile and any responses from the batch will be placed on the screen. Personally, I use `EDITPLUS` which can be set up to colour-highlight keywords and overcomes some of `NOTEPAD`'s bad habits

Comment: the `ECHO` keyword will simply DISPLAY a message on the screen, so `ECHO RD "%target%\%%t"` would simply display `RD ".\media files\SOMESUBDIR"` for instance rather than actually executing `RD ".\media files\SOMESUBDIR"` and deleting the subdirectory. Of course, simply deleting the keyword `ECHO` from the line will change its behaviour - instead of DISPLAYING the `RD...` command, the `RD...` command would be executed - along with the directory...

Comment: Adding the `PAUSE` as I have done to the original batch would cause the balack window to remain open if it's simply run as you have done. Using a DOS session is easier, though. Then we need to know quite exactly what the message is. Don't worry - I have a continuous supply of coffee and a LARGE bottle of aspirin...

Comment: Thank you so much for all that info! I did everything you said and it works perfectly now...and I've learnt a few new things :) I ended up saving the .bat file in the parent folder of the 'Media Files' folder as I wanted a one-click access for it run. However I then thought to schedule it to run once a day using the Task Scheduler in Startup-All Programs-Accessories-System Tools. But is there a way for this script to run automatically every time a folder is added in the Media Files directory? I don't think it's possible using Task Scheduler, I tried selecting it to run 'On an Event' but

Comment: couldn't find what I was looking for from the list. Thanks again for the help btw!

Comment: Experienced batchers establish a directory, often named `BATCH` (but I've also seen `BELFRY`) in which to keep their `BAT`s. The trick is to add this directory into the `PATH`. When the OS wants to start a program using just `programname`, it looks in the `CURRENT` directory first, then in each directory of the `PATH` until it finds an executable `programname.EXT` where EXT is itself the sequence of extensions given by `PATHEXT`. You can see the values of these environment variables by executing `set path` from the prompt

Comment: The official way of changing these values is by `Settings>Control Panel>System>Advanced System Settings>Environment Variables` or, if you're game, by using `RegEdit` (but here be dragons). The downside is that the PATH variable is often too long to be properly edited BUT there are utilities available (I use an excellent FREE one called "Path Editor" - Google is your friend) to include your batch file directory into your path.

Comment: As for monitoring for newly-created directories - there are (even free) utilities to do that, but you can of course brew it yourself using batch (which was, after all, used to create the universe - or so I have been told) BUT how to do it is really beyond the scope of this question - try adding another - it's not all that expensive!