# Script to rename files to parent folder, move renamed file and delete empty folder UNIX

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, command

im trying to create a unix version of this (to work on osX) [Script to rename files to parent folder, move renamed file and delete empty folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376485/script-to-rename-files-to-parent-folder-move-renamed-file-and-delete-empty-fold) but have no clue where to start.

If possible, i would also like it to be able to remove a string at the beginning of the folder name. (the folders i got off someone are named "(BLR) moviename","(SD) moviename" and "(HD) moviename" and i would like the remove the tags at the beginning.

may i please have some help?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're going to have to attempt it yourself first.

Comment: I have tried, and failed miserably. all it does is throw errors so i thought i could get some (if any) advice from people who know a lot more about this than myself.

Comment: OK post what you have and we can work through it (or someone will)

Comment: I know it'll probably be a combo of `cp -a ..` and `rm -rf ..` but i have no clue on how to actually do anything :/

Answer (score 0):

The following might work, or give you a starting point:

```
ls -1 '(BLR) '* '(SD) '* '(HD) '* | while read fff; do
NN=`echo $fff | sed 's/^[^ ]* //'`
if [ -e $NN ]; then
    echo "Skipping $fff; $NN already exists"
else
    mv $fff $NN
fi
done
```